# PhoneGap Back Button exit the Application

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

Currently i am working on Mobile Apps using PhoneGap (Cordova 2.2), JQuery and Javascript. Landing Page is Login Page. So once i entered into Dashboard Page using login credentials, when i click the **BACK BUTTON** its returns to the login page not stay on dashboard page. What can i do??? Suggestions welcome.

I've tried,

### SCRIPT

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Call onDeviceReady when Cordova is loaded.
//
// At this point, the document has loaded but cordova-2.2.0.js has not.
// When Cordova is loaded and talking with the native device,
// it will call the event `deviceready`.
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to call Cordova methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
//
function onBackKeyDown() {
    alert("Back Button Clicked"); //called the alert..checking
}

</script>
```

### HTML

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
</body>
```

My onDeviceReady and onBackKeyDown Function not working / Fired. Am i missing something???

Comment: Basically you want to say that your application should again go to Dashboard although your current page is dashboard. The behavior what you stated is maintaining session, but using phonegap we are not doing it.

Comment: we don't have back button in my HTML Page. But in mobile, we have a back button right??? Now what's the solution????

Comment: Then that backbutton will directly close your application, and when you open the application again, it will take you to dashboard. You have maintain your credentials in local storage of mobile.

Comment: is it jquery mobile page ?

Comment: We have used Cordova-2.2.js and jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Try with loggin variable to check if login and do something on the call back function.

```
function onBackKeyDown(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();
     evt.stopPropagation();
     if(loggedin=='yes'){
         //dont do anything or show popup
     }else{
         history.back();
     }
}
```

You need to bind the eventLinstener first, and call the **app.initialize()** in the page onLoad OR $(document).ready() method.

```
 var app = {
 // Application Constructor
   initialize: function() {
       this.bindEvents();
   },

   // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
   // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
   bindEvents: function() {

      document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);

   },

   onDeviceReady: function() {
       document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
   }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But my situation what is not onBackKeyDown event triggered / fired??? Am i missing something???

Comment: is your onDeviceReady() called? (check with an alert)

Comment: no both onDeviceReady and onBackKeyDown not triggered :(

Comment: Yeah, i wrote that. call the "app.initialize()" method on document.ready() method. THAT MEANS: $(document).ready(function(){app.initialize();});

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63761/discussion-between-karthik-n-and-riad).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    //after successful  login
        localStorage.setItem('login', 1);
// and your back function callback
        function onBackKeyDown(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var isLogin = localStorage.getItem('login);
        if (isLogin){
        // stay here
        } else {
        history.back();

        }
           }
```

Comment: My problem is both onDeviceReady and onBackKeyDown not triggered :( – Am i missing something???

Comment: you included cordova js ?

Comment: might be version mismatching of cordova . do you have cordova-2.2.0.js in root(www) ?

Comment: have you got the jar file of 2.2.0 ? any specific reason to use 2.2.0 ? we have 3.6 now

Comment: no reason behind that... we have jar file of 2.2.0. and cordova.2.2.0.js files. My Question is, whatever version we have, but why onDeviceReady and onBackKeyDown not working / fired???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63762/discussion-between-karthik-n-and-ashish-nautiyal).